# Reading / Writing custom file attributes with C++/Java

Tags: java, c++, windows

I am implementing a simple Windows Overlay Icon Handler in C++ and I want to decide with a property of the document whether to show overlay icons or not. However, this property will be a custom property and will be given with my Java application. Below you can see a piece of sample Java code. Is it possible to read this property that I set in Java with C++?

```
try {
     Files.setAttribute(Paths.get("my file path"), "user:status", "10".getBytes("UTF-8"));
} catch (IOException exception) {
     exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

I tried the property example from windows tutorial [here.](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appplatform/PropertyEdit) but that code only giving me system attributes. You can see the output of this code below [sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr6yF.png)

I'm trying the read that custom attribute of file on overlay icon handler and decide whether to show overlay icons or not. I guess my C++ method would look like this.

```
HRESULT __stdcall CIconHandler::IsMemberOf(LPCWSTR pwszPath, DWORD dwAttrib)
{
   //get file attributes
   // read user:status attribute value
   // if (value = 15) {show icon}
   // else { don't show icon }
}
```

And if you have other solutions or suggestion for this operation I'm open for them.

Comment: Which filesystem are you using? Are you sure the attribute has actually been set?

Comment: NTFS. Yes I'm sure attribute has actually been set because I can read it with Files.getAttribute in Java

Comment: Java will probably be using an alternative [File Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-streams) (files can have multiple streams) to save the attributes. You will need to determine which one (enumerate them using WinAPI) and then you should be able to read the attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. Can you provide any examples for this I'm really new to C++ and windows file systems. @RichardCritten

Comment: Data streams can be enumerated using the [`FindFirstStreamW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirststreamw) and [`FindNextStreamW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextstreamw) functions.

Comment: Here's what Java's doing if that helps: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/15345e3edcd8beee0d2c3192cfaaf76c7accee1f/src/java.base/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsUserDefinedFileAttributeView.java#L177